# popup an image and hide all index

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a game (learning and experimental Purpose).
I want to the game show like a "popup" image when you lose, I tryed to hide all divs but is not working...
What I want to do is when you lose the image is displayed in the same screen, such facebook images or twitter, that background fades and the image is shown.
in my game, when someone lose, I added an image but it seems like this: 
[image: unlikely image message]

```
        function show_image() {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = 'images/firstblood.png';
        img.width = 300;
        img.height = 300;

        // This next line will just add it to the <body> tag
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
```

The function above is called when someone lose in game.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code?

Comment: @VinnyMannello Already did

Comment: so what is the current result? Does it half work?

Comment: With out more code the best I can suggest is to look up z-index properties. You will want an element to cover up the viewport with a higher z-index than the content. Then you can have another element with an even higher z-index to lay on top of the cover up. Focus more on CSS and less on JS to get this done.

Comment: @VinnyMannello So css will make this possible by adding it.. so you suggest me to add the image through html, and custom it with css so it will be more helpful?

Comment: Well, css will give you the framework for the mechanism. Switching the visibility to make it appear will be done with JS. No need to add the image with javascript, unless something about the image is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is much more than just appending an image do your HTML DOM.

I know you want to keep it simple, but just for the sake of it, checkout [AngularJS' ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow). This will hide or show elements in your DOM structure whenever you want them to.

A very simple solution to this is provided in [this snippet of code](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_popup_image). It injects the basic JQuery library which provides functionality to show popup windows with ease. Just follow the code in the snippet and you should be good to go.

Comment: @CarlosMontiel Happy to help.

If you are still looking for that fading background, have a look as [this code snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/zrMTd/2/).